# Windows 10 WiFi keeps disconnecting. Event Viewer: The computer is roaming too often. The security check did not complete after several attempts

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, wireless-router

I am running Windows 10 Home (10.0.17134 Build 17134). Recently, the WiFi started to disconnect very frequently. (Once every 5 minutes or so.) Once disconnected, it usually takes about 30 seconds for it to reconnect.

There is an Android phone and a Mac Book Air right next to the laptop and they had no problem using the WiFi.

I went to Event Viewer and I noticed that every time it disconnects, an error is thrown:

```
WLAN AutoConfig service failed to connect to a wireless network.

Network Adapter: Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560
Interface GUID: {fa873ec0-866a-4877-8e6a-3cb55e667d25}
Connection Mode: Automatic connection with a profile
Profile Name: HOME-2.4
SSID: HOME-2.4
BSS Type: Infrastructure
Failure Reason:The computer is roaming too often. The security check did not complete after several attempts.
RSSI: -59
```

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Attempts made:

- Restart router/laptop
- Forget network and reconnect
- Put the laptop in front of A/C to cool it down
- Quit every software and the WiFi still keeps disconnecting

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I will try that. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Same problem on Lenovo X1 Yoga.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue on a Win 10 PC stick.
I just now enabled my Event Viewer log for "**WLAN AutoConfig**" > "**Diagnostic**" log. (So I can't see my error yet.)

> [You already did this, but for anyone else: How to enable Diagnostic
> log for **WLAN AutoConfig** : https://superuser.com/a/1071150 ]

But according to your log, it's a **Roaming issue**:
*"Failure Reason:The computer is roaming too often."*

What I did was change my roaming settings, and the Disconnects decreased (but I still have an issue, and need to view my log updates.)

Step 10 (for Windows 10) at this link: https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-us/sln285293/change-the-intel-advanced-wi-fi-adapter-settings-to-improve-slow-performance-and-intermittent-connections?lang=en#Windows_10

*"In the Property: box, touch or click **Roaming Aggressiveness and select 1. Lowest** from the drop-down menu under Value:."*

There are other settings to check, such as to change the frequency width or band, to help choose a less busy one. And chose 2G or 5G (whatever works best for you).

> [Details: I hate Win 10 so much. I think the problem is Win10 is doing
> stealth updates/changes - which is affecting Wifi settings. (I now have a Win10 update Blocker, and Wifi was working. But now something got thru, and Wifi disconnects again.)
>
> When I
> first got the PC stick, it had Wifi issues. I tried "updating" the drivers
> and all that BS. But I think a Win10 forced driver update might have caused
> the errors - as factory Wifi driver was working better.
>
> I searched for answers and
> **disabled Power saving (in the Device Manager > Wifi adapter (Intel))**. I think this fixed the issue. But months later,
> the Wifi is disconnecting again (and I forgot what settings I changed
> to fix the first time - Power save is still off, but I changed something else to fix).
>
> So now I set Roaming Aggressiveness to lowest (but perhaps before the
> Win10 stealth changes, it was at 1, and I didn't know).]

Comment: It is no longer an issue for me, as I have already switched my laptop. I don't know if this will help future visitors of this question, but I hope it will, so I am going to accept this answer for now.