# How to check what is controlling/restarting a Windows Service or view its errors?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe, services, command-history

There are services which can be found in `services.msc`

As example, `WlanSvc` the WLAN AutoConfig.

How can I check which "thing" initiated a Stop or a Restart on a service?

With "thing", I could mean any application or maybe even auto-executing command lines.

Or if it was the service itself, since there are properties if you Right-click a service and check "Recovery", that apparently can make a service automatically restart if errors were found. How can I view and check those errors?

Comment: @John Is that something I have to keep running in the background, or can it also check past events? And is there a way to load things faster?

Comment: @John What format does "Time of day" have to be in?

Comment: @John it doesn't seem like that Process Monitor is able to see past events unless I leave it running. So it's not really a log.

Comment: @John I closed the program and it did not show me processes from the past minutes.

Comment: Some events can be found in the Event Viewer.

Comment: @harrymc I only see warnings from WlanSvc not "Errors". Unless "Recovery" properties restarts the service for Warnings as well? Event 4003

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://superuser.com/questions/1425196/windows-10-wifi-keeps-disconnecting-event-viewer-the-computer-is-roaming-too-o? Additionally, look over https://msft.today/wlan-autoconfig-keeps-stopping/d for some tips to potentially help you resolve the intermittent issue.